# Convert specific time format to epoch format?

Tags: javascript, datetime-format

How do I convert this "12:30 pm Today" format to epoch format?

Comment: how dose your specified format look when the date is not today/yesterday?

Comment: Sorry that I made you to loose your time. I have deleted my answer because it is completely wrong, I just got confused because the result is very close to `Date()`. I was also unsucessfully trying with _momentjs_. Good luck with it and if I get to know a way I will post it. In the meanwhile, answer the comment of MoLow, it can be useful to know that.

Comment: I converted "12:30 pm Today" to GMT format first and then I applied your moment.js formula to the GMT format.
That way I made it work... Thanks!